# Getting IllegalArgumentException during passing image to report

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I'm trying to pass an image as a parameter in JasperReports' report. This is is the code am using on my servlet:

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource("/photos/0006.jpg"));
```

Then I'm getting the error below:

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: 1) You should post the full stacktrace. 2) You should post small code (Java + jrxml) to reproduce the problem. 3) Did you try to debug code? `this.getClass().getResource("/photos/0006.jpg")` - Did you check result of this call?

Comment: Where is image stored now? In project resources folder? Show us resources folder structure

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me guyz, thanks

BufferedImage image = null;

```
    try {
        String path = "/Admin/Gallery/students/photos";
        File file = new File(getServletContext().getRealPath(path) + "/" + student.getPhoto());
        image = ImageIO.read(file);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```